# scrapy middleware for skip some page

Tags: python, scrapy

i want got data only from pages where "name" contains some pattern
other pages i want skip.

Now it is so

```
def parse_item(self, response):
  item=Item()
  item['name']=response.xpath('//title//text()').extract().first()
  if "pattern" not in item['name']:
    return []
  else:
    return item
```

how to make it as middleware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sad to answer my own question, but what can i do...

```
   def process_response(self,request, response, spider):
        if not spider._rules:
            return response
        rule_index=request._meta.get('rule',None)

        response_callback=None
        if rule_index != None:
            rule = spider._rules[rule_index]
            response_callback=rule.callback


        if response_callback and response_callback == getattr(spider,self.settings['PARSE_FUNCTION']):
            ## do something
        return response
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [`Downloader Middleware`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.DownloaderMiddleware.process_response) specifically because of the `process_response` it offers

from scrapy.exceptions import IgnoreRequest

```
class SkipMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        if spider.name == 'myspider' and request.callback == spider.parse_item:
            if 'pattern' not in response.xpath('//title//text()').extract_first():
            raise IgnoreRequest
        return response
```

remember to [activate it](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#activating-a-downloader-middleware)

Comment: but it for all pages

Comment: can make it only for parse_item() ?

Comment: Never thought of using middlewares for this kind of ordeal +1, thanks

Comment: can get spider name in __init__ ?

Comment: request.callback always _response_downloaded

Comment: sorry I didn't test the middleware, it should be ready now, I was missing the `self` argument and to return a `response`

Comment: it shouldn't return that, how did you activate your middleware? what order is it in?, do you have more middlewares?

Comment: middleware second in order of DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES

Comment: ok looks like you are using a `CrawlSpider` I am afraid I can't get the respective callbacks on that case.